# Sum values of a sum values

Tags: mysql

Table

```
    item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4
    -------+--------+--------+--------
      1 |      1 |      0 |      0
     -------+--------+--------+--------
      1 |      2 |      0 |      0
```

Sql command:

> select *,(item 1 + item 2 ) + (item 1 + item 2 ) as ItemS from MyTable

Wants Result

```
  item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4 | ItemS
    -------+--------+--------+-------------
      1 |      1 |      0 |      0
     -------+--------+--------+-----------
      1 |      2 |      0 |      0
      -------+--------+--------+-----------
                                      5
```

Comment: This is not how SQL works. You cannot do both of these things in one query.

Comment: Tvde1 SELECT 
 *
, ( SELECT 
     SUM(item_1) + SUM(item_2)
    FROM 
     my_table
  ) AS ItemS
FROM
 my_table

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design, so I'd focus on fixing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want the total of all item_1 + item_2 records.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
, ( SELECT 
     SUM(item_1) + SUM(item_2)
    FROM 
     my_table
  ) AS ItemS
FROM
 my_table
```

**Result**

```
| item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4 | ItemS |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------|
|      1 |      1 |      0 |      0 |     5 |
|      1 |      2 |      0 |      0 |     5 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f679ee/5

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need the sum of `item_1 + item_2` from your table

```
select sum(item_1 + item_2 ) as ItemS from demo
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51acd1/2)

Comment: Mr. M khalid  but i want to display all the records